# The POVM representation for 1 qubit using multiqubit Clifford group

Tags: clifford-group, povm

I am studying the multiqubit Clifford group with the aim of utilizing it to generate a POVM for a single qubit. Similar to how the SIC-POVM is generated using four matrices, I aim to accomplish a similar construction. However, for the multiqubit Clifford group, I am currently uncertain about the specific methodology for its construction in this context.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Could you please provide what you did so far or share your ideas how do you think you would proceed?

Comment: Someone told me that by following the standard method for generating the Clifford group, I can obtain a unitary matrix. From each column of this matrix, I can derive a POVM. However, I am unaware of the specifics regarding this standard procedure.